# Android platform not found when using intellij, kotlin multiplatform and gradle

Tags: android, macos, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have an issues with intellij where `platform 'android-31'` is not found when I try to sync the gradle projects in our repo. But the realty annoying thing is all gradle tasks work through the command line and gradle sync works in android studio.

I have tried to reinstall the SDK and intellij, I have also tried using different SDK managers; command line (from homebrew), intellij and the one in android studio.

Environment:

```
Company Macbook Pro (M1 Pro, macos:12.5.1)
$ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{my_username}/Library/Android/sdk
```

```bash
# {repo_root}/local.properties
sdk.dir=/Users/{my_username}/Library/Android/sdk
```

Here is the error

```bash
Module: ':core' platform 'android-31' not found.
```

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: I will need to look into that, I didn't start this project so i'm not too sure how was made, it's kinda complex and close-source.

Comment: Have you installed "Android SDK Platform 31" (Android 12.0 S) using SDK manager?

Comment: @Robert yep, and it work as expected in Android studio, it's just in intellij it can't find `Android SDK Platform 31`. That's was so baffling.

Comment: @y.bedrov I was able to find a open source where the same issue occurs including the fact it works in Android studio. https://github.com/Liftric/KVault

Comment: Please try settings the SDK location for the sdk.dir path in your project's local.properties file: sdk.dir=/path/to/sdk. Please note that this functionality comes from the Android Studio IDE. Please file an issue as per https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs to Android Studio issue tracker if problem remains. Thank you.

Comment: I have bumped into this issue as well. IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 gives that error, while Android Studio works just fine. The sdk path in local.properties is correct, SDK manager shows that the platform is installed. I found a similar ticket - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-298074/Module-app-platform-android-xx-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to download Java 1.8, once that was done IntelliJ recognised the android SDK.